# the WATCH panel disappear when I debug my code in VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

There should be four panels(**VARIABLES, WATCH, CALL STACK, BREAKPOINTS**) on the left side, but now there is only three.

I try my best to find how to open the WATCH, but failed. I can't find related settings in View or Setting.json

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDoHA.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce0gy.png)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run my application and set a break-point.  Right-clicked on a variable and selected "add to watch" and the watch section appeared.

A new "run and debug" icon in the side-bar appeared as well.  It appears that I accidentally dragged the watch section to the sidebar.

I was able to open the "run and debug" menu and drag the new icon off the sidebar and into the menu.  My "Watch" section is now back where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting one variable of your code (double click), and then click with the right button of your mouse, and choose the option "Add To Watch" on the drop-down nenu. The Watch panel will show again.
Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  No "Add To Watch" option when i right-click on a variable name.  Update:  did work for me.  The watch section seems to be in some no-man's land.  Not part of the run & debug menu any more and I can't move it anywhere by dragging it.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me. Somehow watch section inside debug panel became separate panel and i did not notice that at first. Take a closer at look left vscode panel